# iOS Manage User Account in Settings Bundle

Tags: ios, objective-c, settings.bundle

I know we can have define many preferences via [Settings Bundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html)

But I haven't found a way to allow user to add/delete account in app settings - like what Twitter, Facebook have in iPhone settings.

How can I achieve that? Specifically, I want to enable user logout in the settings page instead of inside the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Facebook and Twitter preferences are both built by Apple, they aren't done via the Settings bundle so they can add more than what you are restricted to by the Settings bundle.

The way you'd need to do it would be to have the boolean toggle and explain that when on, the next time they open the app they will be logged out. Then when the app is launched, check if the toggle is on and if so logout then reset the toggle to off.

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: thanks! I've managed to do so. "have the boolean toggle and explain that when on" - how can I *explain* it when the toggle has been updated?

Comment: @xialin I've updated my answer with an example picture